# How to input a value of any datatype and store into a single variable of our choice and then check its datatype?

Tags: c#

How to input a value of any datatype and store into a single variable of our choice and then check its datatype. if i use dynamic datatype,the output is string datatype for all the values at run time. Here is my code....

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the input value");
        dynamic str = Console.ReadLine();
        if (str.GetType() == typeof(int))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This input is of type Integer");
        }
        else if(str.GetType() == typeof(float))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This input is of type Float");
        }
        else if (str.GetType() == typeof(string))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This input is of type String");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This is something else");
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please do not add tags which have nothing to do with your question.  This is a `c#` question, and has nothing whatsoever to do with `java`.

Comment: Check https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline(v=vs.110).aspx and you will see that Console.Readline() always returns a string. You need to rethink your solution. What else have you tried?

Comment: `dynamic` won't help you here... You need to take the value in the string variable and then try to parse that value `int` and `float`. If successfully parsed that means it's either int or float based on which parsing is success. Else the value is string. You can not have something else here as user can enter only string value from the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `TryParse` methods to check if a `string` can be parsed into another data type, like `int`.

Look at these methods (there are more): [Int32.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx), [Int64.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zc2x2b1h(v=vs.110).aspx), [Single.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.single.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx), [Double.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/994c0zb1(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
string input = Console.ReadLine();

if (Int32.TryParse(input, out _))
{
    // input is int
}
else if (Single.TryParse(input, out _))
{
    // input is float
}
else
{
    // input is neither int nor float
}
```